# Should I resend CV if I just have an accepted paper after submitting the application?

Tags: cv, job

I recently applied for several assistant professor positions. Today I was just told the paper I submitted was accepted. Also, I just had a presentation accepted by a conference.
In this case, should I contact the universities I applied for to update my CV?

Comment: What's your field? Most STEM-related searches are about to be over by now.

Answer (score 1):

Most searches move slowly, so if you contact everyone with an updated CV, you may have to update them again later (and later again and again), which will really annoy some search chairs (I can attest to this, having served as chair on search committees).

Best approach? Wait until there is another reason to interact with the search committee. For instance, if you are going to talk with them on the phone, see them at a conference, or even if they call you to clarify something, then you tell them that your CV has been updated and you want to send them a new CV. If your initial CV was fairly strong.

Did you indicate that these works were under review when you first submitted your CV? A good rule of thumb - when on the job search, put the titles of papers on your CV as under review and leave off the name of the journal you submitted to in order to.

Good luck!!!!